# Timer - counting down and displaying result in specific format

Tags: java, date, countdown

I have counter, you set a date, and then you can get time to this date, but I need display it in chosen format.

EG:
If I have 1 day, 13 hours, 43 minutes and 30 seconds left, and set format to:

> "You have: #d# days, #h# hours, #m# minutes to die"

Then just display:

> "You have 1 day, 13 hours, 43 minutes to die"

But if you set format to:

> "You have: #h# hours, #m# minutes to die"

Then I need display:

> "You have 37 hours, 43 minutes to die"

(so missing type (days) are converted to other (hours))

---

I have this code:
PS: S,M,H,D,W that just second in milliseconds, minutes in milliseconds etc...

```
public static String getTimerData(long time, String format) {
    int seconds = -1, minutes = -1, hours = -1, days = -1, weeks = -1;
    if (format.contains("#s#")) {
        seconds = (int) (time / S);
    }
    if (format.contains("#m#")) {
        if (seconds == -1) {
            minutes = (int) (time / M);
        } else {
            minutes = (seconds / 60);
            seconds %= 60;
        }
    }
    if (format.contains("#h#")) {
        if (minutes == -1) {
            hours = (int) (time / H);
        } else {
            hours = (minutes / 60);
            minutes %= 60;
        }
    }
    if (format.contains("#d#")) {
        if (hours == -1) {
            days = (int) (time / D);
        } else {
            days = (hours / 24);
            hours %= 24;
        }
    }
    if (format.contains("#w#")) {
        if (days == -1) {
            weeks = (int) (time / W);
        } else {
            weeks = (days / 7);
            days %= 7;
        }
    }
    return format.replace("#w#", Integer.toString(weeks)).replace("#d#", Integer.toString(days)).replace("#h#", Integer.toString(hours)).replace("#m#", Integer.toString(minutes)).replace("#s#", Integer.toString(seconds));
}
```

And... any better way to do that?

Answer (score 3):

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy MM dd");
String text = date.toString(formatter);
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(text, formatter);
```

more info [here](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

or, if you're not using java8 [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: I need something without using other API. (I writing something small, and only as add-on)

Comment: Java 8 is not an "other API".

Comment: Ach... I thought this is "joda-time". But I must use java 7 ;/

Comment: @user2250333 it is there in java7 as well as java6, java 5, etc

Comment: @MartinAsenov Eclipse can't find that

Comment: @MartinAsenov But that just displays a date, I need something to counting down like: `You have 3 hours and 30 minutes to die`, or `You have 210 minutes to die` where first using `You have #h# hours and #m# minutes to die` and second using `You have #m# minutes to die` pattern.

Comment: This Answer does not address the Question.

Answer (score 1):

## Joda-Time

If your goal is the words spelling out "1 day, 13 hours, and 43 minutes", then [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) has a class exactly for that purpose: [`PeriodFormatterBuilder`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/PeriodFormatterBuilder.html). Using that class is easier that trying to write your own. See examples in other answers such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21002803/642706) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2179831/642706).

## java.time.*

The new [java.time.* package](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/format/package-summary.html) in [Java 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) may have something similar given that it is inspired by Joda-Time. Perhaps the [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html) class in the [java.time.format package](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/format/package-summary.html).